# How to draw a tangent to a surface in a given direction?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, graphics3d, geometry

It seems quite embarrassing for me, but somehow I can't draw a tangent line to a surface in a given direction.  Assume that I want to visualize directional derivative of the function, say, $(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$, at the point, say, $(1,0.5)$.  I tried this:

```
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

Manipulate[
 Show[{Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]},
      {ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[phi]*t,Sin[phi]*t,
         ((D[F[x, y], x] /. x -> 1 /. y -> 0.5)*Cos[phi]
         + (D[F[x, y], y] /. x -> 1 /. y -> 0.5)*Sin[phi])*t},
      {t, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick]}], {phi, 0, 2*Pi, Pi/4}]
```

to no avail.  (I am a bit afraid that I did make some stupid *mathematical* error; unfortunately, Mathematica's syntax is a bit "perlish" to me: I'm learning to write in it, but have serious difficulties reading it...)

My question is twofold: (1) what is wrong with the above code and (2) what is a "canonical" (read: elegant and possibly fast) way of doing this?

Comment: To clarify: you want a tangent *line*, not a tangent *plane*?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote: I want to visualize *directional derivatives*, so a tangent line seemed quite appropriate for me;).

Comment: There are tones of cases to get inspired by and downlaod source code from here: http://bit.ly/MAF6D6 and here: http://bit.ly/NJjKzF

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov: thank you, I'll look at them; still, I'd like to know why my code didn't work...

Comment: @mbork The equation for the tangential line should be `{x,y,F[x,y]} + {Cos[phi] t, Sin[phi] t, (D[F[x,y], x] Cos[phi] + D[F[x,y], y] Sin[phi]) t} /. {x -> x0, y -> y0}`

Comment: @Heike: thanks, stupid me: I started with drawing it at point (0,0,0) (in fact, it was even another surface), and forgot to update the starting point.  Shame on me.  Good that it's me who grades the students, not the other way round;P.

Comment: This question is ambiguous due to internal contradictions.  The directional derivative is the projection of a *normal* vector onto the xy plane and thereby is about as different from a "tangent line" as one can get. Moreover, without further constraints, a "tangent line" is not well-defined.

Comment: @whuber: but who said that directional derivative is *the same* as the tangent line???  (And btw, I apparently use a different definition of it, but never mind.)  I only claim that a tangent line is something that may help my students visualize the concept of the directional derivative.  Also, the non-well-definedness of a tangent line for some (most, in a sense) functions is obvious, but it doesn't matter for this very question.  (In fact, I do also aim at visualizing some functions with directional derivatives but not differentiable, too, but this is not the issue here.)

Comment: But what exactly do you want? Do you want to draw the directional derivative or do you want to draw (a) tangent line? Your code and part of your question appear to ask for a projection of the directional derivative but you refer to "tangent line" in the title and the text.  If you want a tangent line, then--bearing in mind that a surface has a tangent *plane* at every smooth point--how do you want to select a cross section of that plane bundle?

Comment: OK, so it seems that either it's not only me who can't read Mathematica code, or my code is really bad (probably the latter).  Given a function $f$ from (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}$, a point $(a,b)$ in its domain and a direction $\phi$ on the *plane*, I want to draw a ray starting at $(a,b,f(a,b))$ tangent to the graph of $f$ (provided that anything like that does exist) and such that its projection onto the plane $z=0$ has direction $\phi$.

Answer (score 6):

Try this variation. I didn't really change much, just spelled things out in a way I find to be more clear. It does seem to show directional derivative lines. Also I made the items in `Show` to be a flat list in case having two lists was causing trouble.

```
Manipulate[
  Module[{dirderiv, x, y, base},
    dirderiv = ({D[F[x, y], x], D[F[x, y], y]} /. {x -> pt[[1]], y -> pt[[2]]}
               ).{Cos[phi], Sin[phi]};
    base = {pt[[1]], pt[[2]], F[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]]};
    Show[{
       Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 50], 
       ParametricPlot3D[
           base + t*{Cos[phi], Sin[phi], dirderiv}, {t, 0, 2}, 
           PlotStyle -> Thick
       ]
    }]
  ], 
  {phi, 0, 2*Pi, Pi/4}, 
  {pt, {-2, -2}, {2, 2}}
]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Answer to (2):** As I said in the comment, there are tons of cases to get inspired by and download source code from here:

- [**directional derivative**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=directional%20derivative) at Demonstrations Project
- [**tangent surface**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/search.html?query=tangent%20surface) at Demonstrations Project

**Answer to (1):** too many **{ }** inside `Show`. To make your code work *without paying attention to mathematics* do this:

```
F[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

Manipulate[

 Show[

  Plot3D[F[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
   Mesh -> False],

  ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[phi]*t, 
    Sin[phi]*
     t, ((D[F[x, y], x] /. x -> 1 /. y -> 0.5)*
        Cos[phi] + (D[F[x, y], y] /. x -> 1 /. y -> 0.5)*Sin[phi])*
     t}, {t, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> Thick]

  ] , {phi, 0, 2*Pi, Pi/4}]
```

[image]